# django (1.11) manytomanyfield templatetags filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

The task is this: There are doctors, there are specializations. A doctor can have several specializations. It is necessary to draw a conclusion of the list of Doctors by specialization.

#### Model:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Имя')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Фото')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Создано')
    special = models.ManyToManyField('Specialization')
    experience= models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Стаж', blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Категория', blank=True)
    content = RedactorField(verbose_name='Контент')
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Врача'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Врачи'

    def __str__(self): # For Python 2, use __unicode__ too
        return self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('show_doctor', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


class Specialization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Название')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Создано')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Специализацию'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Специализации'

    def __str__(self):  # For Python 2, use __unicode__ too
        return self.name
```

#### Templatetags:

```
from django import template
from doctor.models import Doctor, Specialization

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('doctors_list.html')
def get_doctors_list(request):
    special_list = Specialization.objects.all()
    return {
        'doctors_list': Doctor.objects.filter(special=special_list),
        'spec_list': special_list
    }
```

#### HTML Template:

```
{% for s in spec_list %}
    <h3>{{ s.name }}</h3>
    <ul>
    {% for d in doctors_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'doctor_detail' d.slug %}">{{ d.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Should be: [PrtSc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHsOx.png) . I can not figure it out, help me)

Comment: You want to remove the bullets?

Comment: You shouldn't create a template-tag to fetch instances from the database. The template shouldn't communicate with the db directly. Instead, what you want is to create a [View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/). The view will pass some context to the template to render. What you should pass is the list of doctors you want to render. In the template, you can then filter and style the result based on specialization.

Comment: I would like to see a more visible solution. I did the same thing through Views - the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

You are going about Django in a totally wrong way when you use a template tag for this purpose. Data is passed to the template through context variables. In your case you nedd a [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) over a `Specialization` queryset. You should access the doctors through the reverse relation in the `Specialization` model (`doctor_set`). Do add a `prefetch_related` for that value to the queryset too.